# Can I build nodes in packages separately?

Tags: ros, catkin, package, node, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I build nodes in packages separately and use own CMakeLists for them?
One of my nodes can't use C++ 11, but other depends on it. Also I want to separate them to git-submodules.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255080/can-i-build-nodes-in-packages-separately?/) by [markovalexey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27531/markovalexey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to write your CMakeLists so as to compile some nodes with C++11 and some without. It will require a little bit of CMake logic.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0